# Filter array based on 2 values not working

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [active_x] => 0
    [active_y] => 0
    [regions] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [x] => 0
                    [y] => 0
                    [name] => The Campground
                    [monsterProbability] => 5
                    [monsterDifficulty] => 1
                    [monsterType] => earth
                )

        )

)
```

This array can contain multiple arrays inside of the `regions` key.

I'm creating a function that will give me the data for a specific region inside the `regions` key, based on `active_x` and `active_y`.

I've tried using `array_filter()`, but I get no return.

The array above is called `$map`:

```
$x = $map['active_x'];
$y = $map['active_y'];

$data = array_filter($map['regions'], function ($var) {
    return ($var['x'] == $x && $var['y'] == $y);
});

echo "<pre>".print_r($data, true)."</pre>";
```

How can I retrieve only the array containing the information for the specific active region?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it should work, as long as you get `$x` and `$y` into the scope of your callback.

```
$data = array_filter($map['regions'], function ($var) use ($x, $y) {
    return ($var['x'] == $x && $var['y'] == $y);
});
```